# string matching(DNA) with 1 mismatch allowed

Tags: algorithm

I need a very fast efficient algorithm for string matching of DNA pattern with atmost 1 mismatch allowed.I have tried boyer-moore-horspool algorithm,but it exceeds the required time.
The length of Text and pattern can be atmost 100000.Please suggest me a very fast alorithm on which i can start working to get this problem resolved.

Comment: You could try N-grams (or K-mers, as they are called in genetics)

Comment: What exactly are the inputs to the routine that gives you match or no match?

Comment: what's a 'match with one mismatch' exactly? if taken literally (one position where two strings are different), you could just iterate both strings at the same time and count mismatches. if the count exceeds 1 then there's no match.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I am also looking to match strings that allow three mismatches

Answer (score 1):

You could try a Hamming distance algorithm, with distance = 1

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance